# Floating elements next to each other with differing heights

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-float

I am trying to place elements next to each other in a fixed width container, where these elements may have different heights (perhaps a max-height could be involved for a range).

This is what I have tried:
https://jsfiddle.net/kc6uyr3d/1/

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 550px;
}
.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
}

.two {
  height: 150px;
}
```

What I am trying to do is shown here:
[image: Result needed]

Anyone can help me achieve this?

Comment: The is a library called Masonry which will do that for you, which is more described in the dupe link. That link also contain a few alternative ways

Comment: ah great, thats for the tip